# How to get Video Metadata of video in IOS Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, video, metadata

I am trying to get the video name from the metadata of a video source file in IOS app using Objective c, Cocoa Framework. I am using the following code

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSArray *metadata = [playerItem.asset metadata];
```

this url is @"http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"

I used the same AvPlayerItem class for retrieving the metadata from an audio file as this below:

```
NSArray *metadata = [playerItem.asset metadata];
for (AVMetadataItem *metadataItem in metadata)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",metadataItem.commonKey);
    [metadataItem loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon] completionHandler:^{

        if ([metadataItem.commonKey isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {
            title = (NSString *)metadataItem.value;
        }
    }];
}
```

Here the commonkey 'title' will help me get the audio file name from metadata, but in case of video the same does not work. While debugging I am getting array as below

<__NSArrayM 0x14c777b50>(

As you can see, the commonKey = software whereas it should have been 'title'. Is there any way to get the video name from the metadata? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I'm trying to get metadata from Video's in camera roll/Photos.

Comment: I think I was able to find it within the object returned by carefully observing the object by debugging. It was several objects deep. Unfortunately, I don't remember how I solved it. I guess I should I have posted it then. Sorry.